# Increasing radius parameter of Foursquare API request omits nearby venues

Tags: foursquare

I am using the [Venues platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) to search for venues under the category "Food" given a latitude and longitude.

Here's the request I started out with:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.783207,-122.441673&limit=50&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&intent=checkin&radius=520&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20120721

This gives me the desired results, however, if I increase the radius from 520 to 5200, I get venues, but I lose venues that are nearby.

I think this is because I limit the results to 50 venues (max allowed by Foursquare) and there are more than 50 venues within a 5200 meter radius. In this case, it seems like Foursquare gives me back the 50 most popular places, which omits some venues. I'd like to have this larger radius, but make sure I get back the venues closest to me.

Are there other parameters that I need to include for this to happen? How can I make sure I get back the nearest venues within a large radius?

Comment: what happens when you switch the `intent=checkin` parameter for a `intent=browse` ? (according to the provided documentation, the `checkin` finds results that a user is **likely** to check in to, as opposed to `browse` which finds venues within a given area).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want reasonable quality venues that are physically close to the user, don't specify a radius at all for intent=checkin -- the default is dynamic based on the density of venues nearby.

intent=browse will give you the top venues in an area without a proximity bias.